# How to keep Swing GUI open, but not stopping other programming processes?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I got some problem with my problem when a Swing GUI window is shown.

The program is checking after new files in a directory in an while loop. If there are new files, it reads it. Some processing are done to the file. Then it is a if statement that checks if the processing is done correctly. If that's not true, a Swing GUI window is shown. The program should not stop checking after new files in the directory. The same process should keep on going even when the Swing window is showing.

```
while(true){
File f = checknewfile();
   if(newFile){
   processing();
     if(processing.ntgood){
     window.setVisible();
       }else{
       }
   }
}
```

But that's my problem, when the window is up, the program stops checking after new files, and the new files don't get their processing done.

How can I solve this problem? 
Thanks for your help!

Comment: everything inside endless loop while(true) has an issue with Concurency in Swing, means all updates to Swing GUI must be done on Event Dispatch Thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`EventQueue.invokeLater`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/EventQueue.html) to start your UI, that way it will be shown on the DispatcherThread instead of your main thread

Comment: Ive tried now with the EventQueue.invokeLater. It worked in a way. The only problem is that the file processing() are not been done when a new file is put in the directory...

Comment: That must be related to your other code in my opinion. I suggest you try to get that running with no gui then adding the GUI, or otherwise post a new question regarding the file reading. If this works without gui but the issue comes after starting the GUI then please update the question with the code you use for processing the files

Answer (score 1):

You can either define a javax.swing.Timer to check this let's say every 10 msec the file appearing and show your window

OR start a new thread and when the check is true call the `window.setVisible();` inside `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` or `invokeAndWait();`

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
 while(true){
 File f = checknewfile();
  if(newFile){
   processing();
    if(processing.ntgood && !window.isVisible()){
      java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
         window.setVisible();
      }});
    }else{
   }
  }
 }
```

Comment: How do you check if window.SetVisible()?